# InFluxQL remove items from result set

Tags: influxdb, influxql

The query below returns several values

```
SELECT non_negative_derivative("signal_wait_time_ms", 1s) 
FROM "sqlserver_waitstats" WHERE ("sql_instance" =~ /^$Instance$/) 
AND $timeFilter GROUP BY "wait_type"
```

returns

```
PWAIT_EXTENSIBILITY_CLEANUP_TASK
SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD
WRITELOG
PAGEIOLATCH_SH
ASYNC_NETWORK_IO
PAGELATCH_EX
SLEEP_BPOOL_STEAL
PAGELATCH_SH
SOS_PHYS_PAGE_CACHE
BACKUPIO
CMEMTHREAD
PAGEIOLATCH_EX
IO_COMPLETION
LCK_M_SCH_M
BACKUPTHREAD
```

I would to filter out 2 values from the list just not sure how.
I would like to EXCLUDE ***"PWAIT_EXTENSIBILITY_CLEANUP_TASK"*** and ***"SLEEP_BPOOL_STEAL"***
from the result set